# Use the principle of induction to show $2+6+18+\ldots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}=3^n-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Show that
>   $$2+6+18+\ldots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}=3^n-1$$

Proving the base case when $n=1$:
$2\cdot3^{1-1}=3^1-1\Leftrightarrow 2=2$

Now doing the induction:
$2\cdot 3^{(n+1)-1}=3^{n+1}-1$
$2\cdot 3^n=3^{n+1}-1$

But I'm kinda stuck here and don't know what to do next

Comment: Have a look at [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to see how to use MathJax on this site. Also [tag:elementary-number-theory] is unrelated, see its tag excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by using proper formulae:

> Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2\cdot 3^{i-1} = 3^n - 1$$

Base case: $2\cdot 3^0 = 2 \checkmark$
Induction hypothesis:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2\cdot 3^{i-1} = 3^n - 1$$
Induction step: Show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} 2\cdot 3^{i-1} = 3^{n+1} - 1$$
Now the LHS is equal to 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2\cdot 3^{i-1} + 2 \cdot 3^{(n+1)-1} \stackrel{\text{i.h.}}= 3^n-1 + 2\cdot 3^n = 3\cdot 3^n - 1 = 3^{n+1} - 1$$
as claimed. $\Box$

More generally:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (p-1) p^k = p^n - 1 \qquad \forall\ p, n$$

Answer (score 1):

you must calculate
$$3^{n}-1+2\cdot 3^n=3^{n+1}-1$$
this is equivalent to
$$2\cdot 3^n+3^n=3^{n+1}$$
$$2\cdot 3^n=3^n(3-1)$$
which is true.

Answer (score 1):

The base case is done, now you assume the Induction Hypothesis and prove it for $"n+1"$.

The way you are stating the problem is wrong, why? Because you want to prove that:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 3^{i-1}\cdot 2 = 3^{n}-1$

Now for the Inductive Step, use your induction hypothesis. Using it will give you:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} 3^{i-1}\cdot 2 = 3^{n}-1 + 3^{n} \cdot 2 =  3\cdot 3^{n}-1 = 3^{n+1}-1$

And that's it.

Comment: You'll want to use `\cdot` for better readability: $2\cdot 3^k$

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove by induction that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2\cdot3^k=3^n-1$

---

First, show that this is true for $n=1$:

- $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{0}2\cdot3^k=3^1-1$

Second, assume that this is true for $n$:

- $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2\cdot3^k=3^n-1$

Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:

- $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}2\cdot3^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2\cdot3^k+2\cdot3^n$
- $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2\cdot3^k+2\cdot3^n=3^n-1+2\cdot3^n$ `assumption used here`
- $3^n-1+2\cdot3^n=3\cdot3^n-1$
- $3\cdot3^n-1=3^{n+1}-1$